# Error about data transfer

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

I am trying to transfer data to python through ajax..
And the error comes like this..

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Here is my html code(js and ajax are included here itself) :

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .html,
        .css {
            height: 175px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #cfd6d9;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            background-color: #f3f5f6;
            padding-left: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="user-container user-html">
            <h3>HTML</h3>
            <div>(Don't put html, head and body tag)</div>

            <div class="editor margin-top-20 html" contenteditable="true"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="user-container user-css">
            <h3>CSS</h3>
            <div>(Write css styles)</div>
            <div class="editor margin-top-20 css" contenteditable="true"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="user-container">
            <h3>Preview</h3>
            <div>(Write css styles)</div>
            <iframe class="user-preview margin-top-20" src="user-file.html"></iframe>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container text-center">
        <button onclick="create_file();">Submit</button>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function create_file() {

            var userhtml = $(".user-html .editor").text();

            var usercss = $(".user-css .editor").text();

            var finalHTMl = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>"+usercss +"</style></head>" +
                "<body>" + userhtml + "</body></html>";

            //Ajax start
            $.ajax({
                url: "test1.py"
                , type: 'POST'
                , data: {
                    'htmldata': finalHTMl
                    , css: usercss
                }
                , success: function (result) {
                    $('.user-preview').attr('src', $('iframe').attr('src'));
                }
            });
            //Ajax End

        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

And this is my python code :

```
def index(req):
        postData = req.form
        json = str(postData['htmldata'].value)
        print(json)
```

Can u guys please tell me where i am wrong

Comment: if you look in the address bar when looking at this page, what do you see before the colon?  "file:" maybe?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Shailesh/Desktop/js/online%20html%20editor/index.html..this is what i see

Comment: You can't use AJAX with the "file" protocol.   You need to have a running web server that knows how to interpret python.

Comment: python has the "SimpleHTTPServer" but I'm not sure it will execute your script (test1.py).  I'm not a python dev, so I'm not positive, but I'm sure an Apache web server can be configured to serve python scripts.